# If Else button pressed in HTML5?

Tags: html, video

I'm doing a simple project for a digital arts class. I want to do a simple little choose your own adventure game, where you watch a clip, then choose from up to several different options on what to do next. Your decision will trigger a video, and the adventure will go on for a little awhile and the player will either escape the haunted house or be killed. This is my first time working with HTML5.

I need to do the following things:
1) When a button is pressed, a certain video is played.
2) After that video ends, the block of text at the top of the screen changes accordingly, presenting players with additional information and explaining their options in greater detail than the clips themselves can provide.

Right now, I just need help with step 1. I can't seem to figure out how to get the button onclick command to work correctly. The program displays the first Intro video just fine, but does not react at all when you click on any of the buttons. I was initially hoping to use something along the lines of an if else button.pressed command, but I can't find anything like that in HTML5. I know its not possible to troubleshoot my code since no one has access to my local files, but I'd appreciate any advice. Thanks!

Here's my code:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Spooks: Choose Your Own Adventure</title>
<script>


function $(id)
    {
    return document.getElementById(id);
    }

    //Video Source Changers

function Door()
{
    $('movie').src = "file:///C:/Users/Spencer/Videos/Spooks/Trapped.mp4" type="video/mp4">
}


function Wander()
{
    $('movie').src = "file:///C:/Users/Spencer/Videos/Spooks/Sesame.mp4" type="video/mp4">
}


function Match()
{
    $('movie').src = "file:///C:/Users/Spencer/Videos/Spooks/Sesame.mp4" type="video/mp4">
}


</script>
</head>


<body style= "background-color: black">

<p style= "color:white">What an awful time to get stranded out in the countryside! It's raining cats and dogs out here. Hungry, freezing, exhausted and desperate, you head to the nearest visible shelter - a decrepit old mansion. Surely southern hospitality will see you safely through the night.</p>

<p>

<video width="400" controls>

  <source src = "file:///C:/Users/Spencer/Videos/Spooks/Intro.mp4" type="video/mp4">

</video>

</p>

<p>
<button onclick="Door()">This is creepy. I'll just go back through the front door.</button>

<button onclick="Wander()">Really weird, but I guess it beats the storm. The owner probably just ran off to get the lights working. I'll wander around a bit, see if I can find him.</button>

<button onclick="Match()">It'd be nice to be able to see before I make a decision one way or the other. Let's light a match...</button>


</p>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like there are a couple of issues.

1) your $('movie').src is invalid javascript, you have some junk code (type="video/mp4">) at the end of the line and the line should end with a semicolon. e.g.

```
function Door()
{
  $('movie').src = "file:///C:/Users/Spencer/Videos/Spooks/Trapped.mp4";
}
```

2) Your video tag doesn't have an id attribute so you are not actually referencing anything in your javascript call to update the src:

```
<video width="400" controls id="movie">
  <source src = "file:///C:/Users/Spencer/Videos/Spooks/Intro.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

I put an updated JSfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/tv7pahcf/

Comment: That solved the problem, thank you so much!Just a quick question; would you happen to know if there's a command similar to button.pressed in regular java in HTML5? 

I want to use if else statements to change the interface based on user's decisions in the game. For example, if they choose to try and go back out the front door, I want the three buttons currently displayed in the code to disappear and be replaced by other buttons. Is this possible in HTML?

Comment: HTML5 is really meant for structure and this kind of functionality is best handled with JavaScript. Take a look at jQuery click events (http://api.jquery.com/click/) which will probably more suited to what you are trying to do.